# unable to find version code in manifest , build failed during bundleRelease why?

Tags: android, react-native

Execution failed for task `:java:packageReleaseBundle`.

one exception was raised by workers:

> com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.manifest.ManifestVersionException$VersionCodeMissingException:
> Version code not found in manifest.

this error is only during `gradlew` `bundleRelease`. please help

below code is  `ANDROID/APP/BUILD.GRADLE`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.textbundle"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        // minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        // targetSdkVersion 23       
        versionCode 9     
        versionName "9.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'mlkit'
    //    renderscriptTargetApi rootProject.ext.renderscriptVersion
    //    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
     
    }



 

       packagingOptions {
       pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    }

   
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }

         release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
              signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

   

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride = versionCodes.get(abi) + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }

     configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.2"
    }
    // resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    //     def requested = details.requested
    //     if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
    //         if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
    //             details.useVersion '25.3.0'
    //         }
    //     }
    // }
}

}
```

below code is  ANDROID/BUILD.GRADLE

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3" //"28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19 //16
        compileSdkVersion = 28 //28
        targetSdkVersion = 28 //28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.3"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "17.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVisionVersion = "17.0.2" 
        renderscriptVersion = 21
        
    }
    repositories {
        // mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
      url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
      }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
        // classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0")
        classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.0.0'
        // classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha09")
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")  
            
        }
             

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/steveliles/maven"
        }
    }
}
```

below is android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.textbundle"  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  

    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>


    <application
       tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
       
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:largeHeap="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       <meta-data
      
      android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
      android:value="ocr, face"
       />
      
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />


       

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution myself.

Go to `android studio >> build >> generate signed bundle`.